How to catch errors in mpi4py?
I'd please like some help debugging an mpi4py program, but then I also have a more general question regarding how to catch errors when using mpi4py.
I've tried several things to catch the errors in my code:

Tried increasing the buffer size
Tried a try/except block

Neither of these seemed to return an error from which I can actually determine what's going on.
Here's the code:
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
from pprint import pprint
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

pprint("-" * 78)
pprint(" Running on %d cores" % comm.size)
pprint("-" * 78)

N = 100000
my_N = N // 8

# Attempt 1):  Change buffer size 
#max_message_size = 1000000  # Set the maximum message size according to your needs
# Create a receive buffer with a larger size
#recv_buffer = bytearray(max_message_size)  # Adjust the size as needed
#comm.Recv(recv_buffer, source=source_rank, tag=tag, status=status)
# end change buffer size 

# Attempt 2) try/except block
try:
    if comm.rank == 0:
        A = np.arange(N, dtype=np.float64)
    else:
        A = np.empty(N, dtype=np.float64)
   
    my_A = np.empty(my_N, dtype=np.float64)
   
    # Scatter data 
    comm.Scatter([A, MPI.DOUBLE], [my_A, MPI.DOUBLE])

    pprint("After Scatter:")
    for r in range(comm.size):
        if comm.rank == r:
            print("[%d] %s" % (comm.rank, len(my_A)))
        comm.Barrier()

    # Allgather data into A
    comm.Allgather([my_A, MPI.DOUBLE], [A, MPI.DOUBLE])

    pprint("After Allgather:")
    for r in range(comm.size):
        if comm.rank == r:
            print("[%d] %s" % (comm.rank, len(A)))
        comm.Barrier()
except MPI.Exception as mpi_err:
    print(" the error was ", mpi_err)


The command used to run, and the resulting output are:
mpirun -n 4 python3 scatter_example.py
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Running on 4 cores'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Running on 4 cores'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Running on 4 cores'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Running on 4 cores'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
 the error was  MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated

You can see both attempts above (Attempt #1 is commented out to make the code runnable).
How do I get an error message that I can interpret?  And why do the above approaches not work? Thank you.
I'm using python3, and running Linux

please edit your question to include the mpirun command line and the error message.

Sure.  I just did, thanks.

since you y_N = N // 8 you should run at least 8 MPI tasks.

That's good to know.  But how do I catch the error?

TL;DR you don't. That being said, there are some tools such as MPI correctness checker by Intel or Marmot from HLRS (cannot find it anymore though) that can assist you doing that (keep in mind they add overhead)

MUST from Aachen University looks like a fit https://www.i12.rwth-aachen.de/go/id/nrbe
